# ASP.NET 2.0 & Web.config: Is this correct <appSettings/>?

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, web-config

I'm looking in Web.Config to add a simple (from a book) amendment -

```
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
   <add key="SupportEmail" value="dfgh@dfghj.com" />. 
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

However in the web.config I see there is only the following sign/bracket/block(?):

```
 <appSettings/>
```

I can't find the opening . And isn't that an incorreect way to write the block?

Or is this a way to tell me I can amend this and add my own opening and closing  block?

Comment: Very elementary XML, my friend! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed amend it (the format /> is a self closing tag which is valid if theres nothing in it)

Comment: I take it that it's a known shorthand to mean 'this is where the block would sit if you had anything to put into it'.

Comment: Yes it's just a bit easier to write when theres nothing to put in it.

For example in XHTML <br /> is obviously easier to type than if you were forced to type <br> </br> (which would be wrong anyway!)

Comment: @Mike: Yes, it's the XML way of saying just that.